# How to read a specific record in a binary file

Tags: c

I have a binary file of students, which is composed by name, number and grade.
How do I prepend the whole binary file and find the student with an x ​​number given by the user?

I want to compare the number entered by the user with the numbers that are in the student database.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <Students.db>

int main(){
char nomeMus[100];

printf("number");
fgets(num,strlen(nomeMus),stdin);

Students a;

    FILE* f;
    f=fopen("aluno.db","r");  

    fseek(f,indexMus*sizeof(Students),SEEK_CUR);
    fread(&a,sizeof(a),1,f);
    printf("the student's name is %s  ",a.name);

}
```

Comment: Please provide a [mcve]. In particular, you should put your code inside `main()` and show the `Students` struct.

Comment: What isn’t working with the code you are showing?

Comment: Are you doing any error checking?  What do you mean by "can't copy user number with database number"?  Are you getting garbage data (eg, fread fails) or are you getting an incorrect record?  It really helps if you give complete code and show samples of your expected vs. actual output.

Comment: ⟼This code could benefit greatly if you adopted an [indentation style](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Indentation_style) and apply it consistently. Indentation conveys structure and intent which makes it easier for us to understand your code without having to invest a lot of time deciphering it.

Comment: This `fgets()` call doesn't make much sense. How does `indexMus` get set? Where does it even come from? Where does `num` get used and why is it being passed in with `strlen(nomeMus)` as the length argument, something to do with a different variable?

Comment: i know the code isnt the best but i really cant do more, this is a homework and my first time working with c

Comment: Sorting it would be a start?